# best way to implement a sql statement binding in C++

Tags: c++, sql, c++11, prepared-statement

Ok so I am writing a DB wrapper in c++0x, the API is in C.

I have preprepared statements which I can bind at runtime.

I would like to bind and execute the statement in 1 function call to the wrapper.

My initial though is to use variation templates. but with the documentation I have seen I have not found out how to limit the types that are entered as template types to fixed set (int, string, double), and how to be able to do basic logic on those types.

something like (pseudo code)

```
foreach arg in args
    if arg1==std::string
        bindToString(arg);
    else if int...
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take advantage of function overloading.

```
void bind(std::string& arg) { bindstring(arg); }
void bind(int& arg) { bindint(arg); }
...

std::vector<boost::variant<double,std::string,int>> args =  {...}
for (auto arg : args)
    bind(arg);
```

-- edit --
Another approach using variadic template

```
void bind(std::string& arg) { bindstring(arg); }
void bind(int& arg) { bindint(arg); }
void bind(void) {}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void bind(T& arg, Args& args)
{
  bind(arg);  bind(args...);
}
```

Comment: I don't know how many variables i need to bind. I need to pass in the prepared statement and any number of objects of any type from a set of types (int double string). so I may need to bind a statement which takes a name and age, or on that takes 6 doubles.

Comment: @111111: Use `boost::variant` and `std::vector` in combination

Comment: ok so this would probably be the best bet, but how would I identify the type of variant at any given point to pass it to the respective C function (ie: bindstring, bindint...). Thanks

Comment: That's what the function overloading is for. Write `void bind(std::string arg) { bindstring(arg); }` and `void bind(int arg) { bindint(arg); }` etc

Comment: @111111 bind() is overloaded with various functions taking arguments of different types. Calling bind(arg) will dispatch calls to the proper function based on which type the variant was constructed with. In `void bind(int arg);`, call `bindint`, etc ...

Comment: yup ok, sounds reasonable to me, Thanks

Comment: Oh and thanks for the variadic template method, i like that the most! Thanks Again